# Twitchy cursor control with MacBook Air trackpad

Tags: touchpad

The trackpad on my old MacBook Air is practically unusable, it is so twitchy. Very frustrating since it worked perfectly before I installed elementary 6 and this bistro looks great otherwise. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "twitchy"? Does the cursor move too quickly? Is it erratic on the screen? Something else? It might also be useful to know which MacBook Air you've installed Elementary on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The Mac is a 2007 13”. The cursor jumps about at the slightest touch, hard to get it to settle where I want it.

Comment: Sorry, that's 2013. A 2007 MacBook Air would be quite something.

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be controlled via the "Mouse & Touchpad" settings.

1. Open your "System Settings" application:
   [image: System Settings]
2. Select "Mouse & Touchpad":
   [image: Mouse & Touchpad]
3. Set the "Pointer Speed" to a value low enough that it feels comfortable

Some touchpads are certainly more sensitive than others. Hopefully this will give you the accuracy you're looking for

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Many thanks.